# Select new column based on existing value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have sample data like below

```
create Table #Temp(id int, Data1 varchar(10), Data2 bigint)

Insert Into #Temp
Values(1,'Value1',109040774),
  (2,'Value2',10000006099758),
  (3,'Value3',10000006099758),
  (4,'Value1',14538),
  (5,'Value2',10000006097458),
  (6,'Value3',10000006097458),
  (7,'Value1',4454834),
```

And trying to select new column based on `Data1`, so the output will be

```
id  Data1   NewColumn
1   Value1  109040774
2   Value2  109040774
3   Value3  109040774
4   Value1  14538      --reset here because same value of Data1 (Value 1 started repeating)
5   Value2  14538
6   Value3  14538
7   Value1  4454834    --reset here because same value of Data1 (Value 1 started repeating)
```

I was trying to use something like below, but not what I after

```
SELECT id, Data1, 
       FIRST_VALUE(Data2) OVER (Partition by Data1 ORDER BY Id  ASC) AS NewCol 
FROM #Temp
Order By Id
```

Any help is appreciate

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  Is `value1` some special value that repeats?  Do all three values repeat in a cycle?  What if one is missing?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Sorry for the confusion, yes they repeat. I updated with some more rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my idea assuming a special `value1` defines a new group:

- Use a cumulative sum to calculate the number of `value1`s on or before each row.
- This defines a grouping.
- Within each group, use `first_value()`.

Hence:

```
select t.id, t.data1,
       first_value(data2) over (partition by grp order by id) as newcolumn
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when data1 = 'value1' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```